# FTPLIB fail to connect Azure VM

Tags: azure, ftplib

I have very strange problem with ftplib. I am using one Azure VM with Ubuntu where an webapp is running. The second Azure VM (customer's) runs FTP server. If I try to connect with Python and ftplib, FTP server refused connection. At the same time, I am able to telnet from the same Azure VM to FTP server. FTP server log shows IP address 127.0.0.1 for my Azure VM when I try to connect with ftplib, and shows correct IP address when I try to connect with telnet. After all, I tried to run the same Python app from my LAPTOP and everything works fine! The customer doesn't use at this moment any firewall, inbound rules etc...
Any idea???

Comment: Any more questions?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, there is no difference between using FTP command and python ftplib to connect the FTP server. And when you connect the FTP through different places, it also affects the result.

If your web app VM and your FTP vm in the same subnet, and there is no NSG or the NSG just associated with the subnet. You can just connect the FTP with the FTP vm private IP.

If your web app VM and your FTP vm in different subnets, and the NSG associated with the subnet. You need to add the rules to allow the traffic to the FTP server in the NSG. Then you can connect the FTP with the FTP vm private IP.

if your web app VM and your FTP vm in different Vnets, and the NSG associated with the subnet. You need to add the rules to allow the traffic to the FTP server in the NSG. Then you can connect the FTP with the FTP vm public IP.

For the FTP server in the VM, you should make sure the FTP listen the right port and the IP `0.0.0.0`. So it can accept all the traffic to this vm with the port.

If you have any more questions, you can give me the messages with the comments.